# Is it possible to use mopidy with Gstreamer 1.10? (Sailfish X)

Tags: python, gstreamer, mopidy

I'm trying to install mopidy on Sailfish OS. However, the only Gstreamer version available is Gstreamer 1.10.4.

I've compiled and installed gst-python 1.10 from source, and the Mopidy 2.1.0 with pip. Howerver, when I launch mopidy, I get the following error :

> ERROR    Unhandled exception in Audio (urn:uuid:9f0eafd5-954e-4d46-8627-f034e9f2789b):
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pykka/actor.py", line 192, in _actor_loop
>       self.on_start()
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mopidy/audio/actor.py", line 437, in on_start
>       self._setup_playbin()
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mopidy/audio/actor.py", line 457, in _setup_playbin
>       playbin = Gst.ElementFactory.make('playbin')
>   TypeError: make() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

It seems the Gstreamer 1.10.4 API isn't compatible with the latest version of mopidy.

I also tried to use mopidy 1.1.2 but it can't find gobject module.
I've replaced all the `import gobject` with `from gi.repository import GObject as gobject` in mopidy's source code but it does not work. I think mopidy <2.0 was intended for Gstreamer 0.10. And mopidy >=2.0 seems intended for Gstreamer >=1.12

How can I make mopidy work with Gstreamer 1.10.4 (on Sailfish X) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working using [this post](https://discourse.mopidy.com/t/trying-to-install-mopidy-on-sailfishos/2083). You basically need to install pygobject2 version 3.15 which you can get from the OBS [here](https://api.merproject.org/package/binary/home:wdehoog/pygobject2?arch=armv8el&filename=pygobject2-3.15.91-10.10.1.jolla.armv7hl.rpm&repository=sailfish_latest_armv7hl).